# Why do we say Tachanun during Adar?

Tags: tachanun, simchah-joy-happiness, adar

According to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10738/1362) answer, we don't say tachanun on days that are yemei simcha -- days of happiness.

But the Talmud (Taanit 29a) says Mishenichnas Adar marbim b'simcha -- once Adar begins we increase happiness. Seemingly this applies at least until after Purim (14th and 15th of Adar).

But if we don't say tachanun in the entire of [Nisan](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47613/1362) because we don't say it for the majority of the month (the rov), then why do we say it during Adar?

Answer (score 1):

While the Talmud does indeed say that, neither the *Rambam* or the *Shulchan Aruch* mention it. *Chasam Sofer* ([OC 160](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=794&st=&pgnum=126&hilite=)) explains why:

> The statement of the Talmud ([*Taanit* 29a](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=29&format=pdf)) "Just as when Av begins we decrease in happiness, so too when Adar begins we increase happiness" is Rav's opinion, following his opinion that the mourning of *Tisha B'Av* applies to the entire month. Thus, just like by Av the mourning applies to the entire month, so too by Adar, the happiness applies to the entire month.
>   
>  However, we do not hold that the mourning applies to the entire month<sup>1</sup>, and therefore there is no longer any reason to say that we should increase in happiness during the entire month of Adar.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [*Taanit* 30a](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=30&format=pdf).

(*Credit: [Double AA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa)*)

Comment: Even according to the way we pasken, Adar 1-15 are still yimei simcha

Comment: @DonielF Do you have a source for that?

Comment: According to the Chasam Sofer’s comparison of Adar to Av, just like we are sad because of Tishah B’av and only until Tishah B’av, in Adar, when we’re happy because of Purim, we should be happy until Purim.

Comment: @DonielF we are not sad "because of Tishah B’av and only until Tishah B’av". Halachicly, the mourning period is only the week of and only until *Tisha B'Av*.

Comment: You Sefardim can mourn for just the week. Us Ashkenazim will keep doing the full nine days.

Comment: @doniel everyone agrees the laws are only the shavua shechal bo. You doing extra bonus customs doesn't change that. The Ashkenzi practice is not fuller or better. It's just extra.

Comment: Ploni, then why does the ShA quote משנכס אב ממעטים בשמחה in OC 551

Comment: @DoubleAA Reducing simcha and mourning are two different concepts. Rav learned "משנכס אב ממעטים בשמחה" as referring to mourning. According to *Shulchan Aruch*, it refers to buildings of joy.

Comment: If it only refers to reduced Simcha then for Adar it should still mean increased Simcha, even if it doesn't mean whatever the opposite of mourning is