# PTIJ: Unknown divine name

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

We have concluded that we indeed say [Tachanun in Adar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89507/15256) in spite of increasing the happiness during the month. However, I'm a bit confused about the introductory verse from [Samuel II 24:14](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08b24.htm#14):

> וַיֹּ֧אמֶר דָּוִ֛ד אֶל־**גָּ֖ד** צַר־לִ֣י מְאֹ֑ד נִפְּלָה־נָּ֤א בְיַד־יְהוָה֙ כִּֽי־רַבִּ֣ים רַֽחֲמָ֔ו וּבְיַד־אָדָ֖ם אַל־אֶפֹּֽלָה׃
>
> And David said unto **God:** 'I am in a great strait; let us fall now into the hand of *Hashem;* for His mercies are great; and let me not fall into the hand of man.'

I don't remember the divine name *God* to be on the list of [Mishneh Torah Yesodei haTorah 6:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/904982/jewish/Yesodei-haTorah-Chapter-Six.htm#v2) Is it possible ח"ח that the great Rambam forgot this name? Due to the gravity of the case, please provide well-sourced answers!

**Edit – Additional confusing questions**

If David used the name *God,* why did he say *hand of Hashem* instead of *your hand?* Did David use a majestic plural or did he want to fall with *God?* How can the latter interpretation be in accordance with the uniqueness of *Hashem?*

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pasuk says: ‘I’ am in a great strait, let ‘us’ fall now into the hand of HaShem... and let ‘me’ not fall into the hand of man.
Why does the pasuk keep switching between singular and plural? Obviously there’s someone else in the room, who he’s talking about when he uses plural, and this person is probably an enemy, because David asks that ‘he’ not fall into the hand of man (meaning his enemies hand), not that ‘they’ not fall into the hand of man. Since most enemies of the Jews are not Jewish, we can assume that this enemy wasn’t Jewish.
Therefore, the pasuk can be explained like this: “and David said to God ‘I, David, am in a great strait, let us (both me and my enemy) fall now into the hands of HaShem, and let me not fall into the hands of my enemy.’”
Because of the (not Jewish) enemy, who might think that the use of ‘God’ was referring to a different deity, David also used the name HaShem, and didn’t say “your hand”.

The reason why God isn’t counted among the names of HaShem is, like I said before, the name ‘God’ can be confused with other deities, and we don’t want non- Jews thinking that their god is our God.

Answer (score 1):

There is no conflict with what Rambam states and what appears in Shmuel II 24:14, which you cite. It isn't referring to the name, ***God***, but to the 42 letter name of G-d which is not supposed to be pronounced.

Hilchot Yesodei HaTorah, 6:1 clarifies that the prohibition against erasing (destroying) one of G-d's seven names is only applying to those names which are actually pronounced.

> **כל המאבד שם מן השמות** הקדושים הטהורים **שנקרא בהם הקב"ה**

The name referenced in Shmuel II 24:14 is [one of those names that is not to be pronounced, namely the 42 letter name of G-d](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/379272/jewish/Uttering-the-Holy-42-Letter-Name.htm) which is formed from the *Roshei Teivot* of the [*Ana B'Koach* prayer](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Preparatory_Prayers%2C_Korbanot%2C_Order_of_the_Temple_Service_(Ana_Bekoach).3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) recited at the completion of reciting the morning Korbanot.

> אָנָּא בְּכחַ גְּדֻלַּת יְמִינְךָ תַּתִּיר צְרוּרָה: קַבֵּל רִנַּת עַמְּךָ שגְּבֵנוּ טַהֲרֵנוּ נורָא: נָא גִבּור דּורְשֵׁי יִחוּדְךָ כְּבָבַת שָׁמְרֵם: בָּרְכֵם, טַהֲרֵם, רַחֲמֵם, צִדְקָתְךָ תָּמִיד גָּמְלֵם: חֲסִין קָדושׁ בְּרוב טוּבְךָ נַהֵל עֲדָתֶךָ: יָחִיד גֵּאֶה לְעַמְּךָ פְּנֵה זוכְרֵי קְדֻשָּׁתֶךָ: שַׁוְעָתֵנוּ קַבֵּל וּשְׁמַע צַעֲקָתֵנוּ יודֵעַ תַּעֲלוּמות:

This 42 letter name is also what one is supposed to have as a mystical *Kavannah* (intention) when reciting [the 42 words of the first paragraph of Shema which starts with V'Ahavta](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Blessings_of_the_Shema%2C_Shema.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

And this name is only hinted at in the posuk from Shmuel which says:

> וַיֹּ֧אמֶר דָּוִ֛ד **אֶל־גָּ֖ד** צַר־לִ֣י מְאֹ֑ד

There is a special kind of letter transformation that is a tradition from Moshe Rabbeinu called *Hakah* (הכאה), as in striking the rock like Moshe did with his staff at G-d's command in [Shemot 17:5-6](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.17.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). In fact, in the posuk cited from Shmuel II, the *bri’ach* between אל and גד reminds us of Moshe’s staff.

This is a photo of the actual rock which Moshe is purported to have struck at Rephidim.

In the context of the source in Shemot from which we learn about this type of letter transformation, it is also understood why the name changes between *HaShem* and the 42 letter name of G-d. *HaShem* was the one who originally revealed this to Moshe Rabbeinu.

[image: Horeb Split Rock]

This transformation is used with 4 letter words. The first two letters are multiplied together for one sum, and the second two letters for a second sum. Then the two sums are added together.

In this particular case, the four letter *word* is formed from *אֶל־גָּ֖ד*. The *bri'ach* between the two words consisting of two letters indicates that they are to be considered as a single word.

So by multiplying 30 and 1 (אֶל) the first sum is 30. Multiplying 3 and 4 (גָּ֖ד) gives a second sum of 12. Adding the two together (30 plus 12) gives a result of 42, which alludes to the 42 letter name which was David's actual intention.

Jest saying...

Answer (score 0):

“God” is not listed as a divine name because of the explicit verse in [Isaiah (65:11)](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1065.htm#11) demonstrating that it is a secular name:

> וְאַתֶּם֙ עֹזְבֵ֣י יְהוָ֔ה הַשְּׁכֵחִ֖ים אֶת־הַ֣ר קָדְשִׁ֑י הַֽעֹרְכִ֤ים לַגַּד֙ שֻׁלְחָ֔ן וְהַֽמְמַלְאִ֖ים לַמְנִ֥י מִמְסָֽךְ׃

Hashem Himself stated that the name “God” is secondary, subservient, secular in regards to divine names. Therefore, David didn’t say “*your* hand” because he was referring specifically to *Hashem’s* hand. The plural “נפלה” could easily have been referring to himself and “God”, indicating that all secular manifestations are subjected (“fall”) to Hashem.